# Contrast algorithm C# pointer to marshal.copy

Tags: c#, vb.net, bitmap, contrast

I tried to translate this code to vb.net using `Marshal.copy` but I can't get it to work

```
for (int y = 0; y < bitmapdata.Height; y++)
{
    byte* destPixels = (byte*)bitmapdata.Scan0 + (y * bitmapdata.Stride);
    for (int x = 0; x < bitmapdata.Width; x++)
    {
        destPixels[x * PixelSize] = contrast_lookup[destPixels[x * PixelSize]]; // B
        destPixels[x * PixelSize + 1] = contrast_lookup[destPixels[x * PixelSize + 1]]; // G
        destPixels[x * PixelSize + 2] = contrast_lookup[destPixels[x * PixelSize + 2]]; // R
        //destPixels[x * PixelSize + 3] = contrast_lookup[destPixels[x * PixelSize + 3]]; //A
    }
}
```

My problem is this line:

```
byte* destPixels = (byte*)bitmapdata.Scan0 + (y * bitmapdata.Stride);
```

Comment: Similar question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174323/contrast-of-an-image-in-vb2005/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have `Scan0` as an `IntPtr` then the naive translation to C# is simply:

```
IntPtr destPixels = Scan0 + y*stride;
```

The players here are:

- `Scan0`: a pointer to the first scanline, i.e. the beginning of the pixel data.
- `y`: the row number.
- `stride`: the number of bytes in a row of pixels.
- `destPixels`: a pointer to the beginning of row `y`.

But this would be under the assumption that you were using unmanaged memory for `destPixels`. I don't know whether or not you are. If you are using managed memory, then the translation would differ. If you want more help you need to tell us about the types that your managed version uses.