# contrast of an image in vb2005

Tags: vb.net, image, visual-studio-2005, contrast

[Adjust the contrast of an image in C# efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115076/adjust-the-contrast-of-an-image-in-c-sharp-efficiently)

solution for above question is not working in vb 2005

i need solution in vb2005

this is c# code below

public static Bitmap AdjustContrast(Bitmap Image, float Value)

{

```
Value = (100.0f + Value) / 100.0f;
Value *= Value;
Bitmap NewBitmap = (Bitmap)Image.Clone();
BitmapData data = NewBitmap.LockBits(
    new Rectangle(0, 0, NewBitmap.Width, NewBitmap.Height), 
    ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
    NewBitmap.PixelFormat);

unsafe
{
    for (int y = 0; y < NewBitmap.Height; ++y)
    {
        byte* row = (byte*)data.Scan0 + (y * data.Stride);
        int columnOffset = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < NewBitmap.Width; ++x)
        {
            byte B = row[columnOffset];
            byte G = row[columnOffset + 1];
            byte R = row[columnOffset + 2];

            float Red = R / 255.0f;
            float Green = G / 255.0f;
            float Blue = B / 255.0f;
            Red = (((Red - 0.5f) * Value) + 0.5f) * 255.0f;
            Green = (((Green - 0.5f) * Value) + 0.5f) * 255.0f;
            Blue = (((Blue - 0.5f) * Value) + 0.5f) * 255.0f;

            int iR = (int)Red;
            iR = iR > 255 ? 255 : iR;
            iR = iR < 0 ? 0 : iR;
            int iG = (int)Green;
            iG = iG > 255 ? 255 : iG;
            iG = iG < 0 ? 0 : iG;
            int iB = (int)Blue;
            iB = iB > 255 ? 255 : iB;
            iB = iB < 0 ? 0 : iB;

            row[columnOffset] = (byte)iB;
            row[columnOffset + 1] = (byte)iG;
            row[columnOffset + 2] = (byte)iR;

            columnOffset += 4;
        }
    }
}

NewBitmap.UnlockBits(data);

return NewBitmap;
```

}

& here is vb2005 code

Public Shared Function AdjustContrast(Image As Bitmap, Value As Single) As Bitmap

```
Value = (100F + Value) / 100F
Value *= Value
Dim NewBitmap As Bitmap = DirectCast(Image.Clone(), Bitmap)

Dim data As BitmapData = NewBitmap.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, NewBitmap.Width, NewBitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, NewBitmap.PixelFormat)

For y As Integer = 0 To NewBitmap.Height - 1
    Dim row As Pointer(Of Byte) = CType(data.Scan0, Pointer(Of Byte)) + (y * data.Stride)
    Dim columnOffset As Integer = 0
    For x As Integer = 0 To NewBitmap.Width - 1
        Dim B As Byte = row(columnOffset)
        Dim G As Byte = row(columnOffset + 1)
        Dim R As Byte = row(columnOffset + 2)

        Dim Red As Single = R / 255F
        Dim Green As Single = G / 255F
        Dim Blue As Single = B / 255F
        Red = (((Red - 0.5F) * Value) + 0.5F) * 255F
        Green = (((Green - 0.5F) * Value) + 0.5F) * 255F
        Blue = (((Blue - 0.5F) * Value) + 0.5F) * 255F

        Dim iR As Integer = CInt(Red)
        iR = If(iR > 255, 255, iR)
        iR = If(iR < 0, 0, iR)
        Dim iG As Integer = CInt(Green)
        iG = If(iG > 255, 255, iG)
        iG = If(iG < 0, 0, iG)
        Dim iB As Integer = CInt(Blue)
        iB = If(iB > 255, 255, iB)
        iB = If(iB < 0, 0, iB)

        row(columnOffset) = CByte(iB)
        row(columnOffset + 1) = CByte(iG)
        row(columnOffset + 2) = CByte(iR)

        columnOffset += 4
    Next
Next

NewBitmap.UnlockBits(data)

Return NewBitmap
```

End Function

Dim row As Pointer(Of Byte) = CType(data.Scan0, Pointer(Of Byte)) + (y * data.Stride)

above line gives error since vb does not support

Dim row As Pointer(Of Byte)

Comment: when code is converted from c# to vb.net it gives pointer error

Comment: Without seeing the VB code you have its impossible to say how to fix the error your getting. You can try converting the code with this tool, http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/. I've used it for simple stuff, seems to work good.

Comment: @Kratz i have udated code the code in vb gives error for pointer(of Byte)

Comment: Check the VB example for the `.Scan0` property here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.scan0.aspx#Y400, since bitmap data is unmanaged, you may have to Marshal the data out, modify it, then Marshal it back in.

Comment: @Kratz but the error is at Dim row As Pointer(Of Byte)which is "'System.Reflection.Pointer' has no type parameters and so cannot have type arguments."

Comment: Right, there really isn't a good translation of the C# line `byte* row = (byte*)data.Scan0 + (y * data.Stride);`, so I think the `as Pointer(Of Byte)` is just invalid. I'm not an expert, but I don't think in VB you can do the same pointer addition you can in C. Also, I believe the pointer `.Scan0` is pointing to unmanaged memory, which I don't think you can access directly in VB.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt at the conversion. I'm using the [`IntPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5he14kz8.aspx) data structure to handle holding the unmanged pointer and to do the pointer addition to get an `IntPtr` for each row. Then as it goes through the row, I'm using the [Marshal.ReadByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhkh8kh.aspx) and [Marshal.WriteByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146670.aspx) methods to handle reading and writing the unmanaged data. I tested and it seems to work.

```
value = (100.0F + value) / 100.0F
    value *= value
    Dim NewBitmap As Bitmap = DirectCast(Image.Clone(), Bitmap)

    Dim data As BitmapData = NewBitmap.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, NewBitmap.Width, NewBitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, NewBitmap.PixelFormat)

    For y As Integer = 0 To NewBitmap.Height - 1

        Dim RowPtr = IntPtr.Add(data.Scan0, y * data.Stride)

        Dim columnOffset As Integer = 0
        For x As Integer = 0 To NewBitmap.Width - 1
            Dim B As Byte = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadByte(RowPtr, columnOffset)
            Dim G As Byte = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadByte(RowPtr, columnOffset + 1)
            Dim R As Byte = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadByte(RowPtr, columnOffset + 2)

            Dim Red As Single = R / 255.0F
            Dim Green As Single = G / 255.0F
            Dim Blue As Single = B / 255.0F
            Red = (((Red - 0.5F) * value) + 0.5F) * 255.0F
            Green = (((Green - 0.5F) * value) + 0.5F) * 255.0F
            Blue = (((Blue - 0.5F) * value) + 0.5F) * 255.0F

            Dim iR As Integer = CInt(Red)
            iR = If(iR > 255, 255, iR)
            iR = If(iR < 0, 0, iR)
            Dim iG As Integer = CInt(Green)
            iG = If(iG > 255, 255, iG)
            iG = If(iG < 0, 0, iG)
            Dim iB As Integer = CInt(Blue)
            iB = If(iB > 255, 255, iB)
            iB = If(iB < 0, 0, iB)

            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.WriteByte(RowPtr, columnOffset, CByte(iB))
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.WriteByte(RowPtr, columnOffset + 1, CByte(iG))
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.WriteByte(RowPtr, columnOffset + 2, CByte(iR))

            columnOffset += 4
        Next

    Next

    NewBitmap.UnlockBits(data)
```

Comment: sorry for late feedback your code seems have been written in vs2010 where i am using vs2005 , vs2005 does not allow IntPtr.Add method